# How to customize the "Insert/edit link" popup box?

Tags: filters, actions, links, tinymce, editor

is there a way to customize the "Insert/edit link" popup box in the editor so that it does something like this:

- Have a checkbox that says "Insert affiliate tag at the end of link"
- If the checkbox is checked, the affiliate code will be automatically inserted after the user hits the "Add link" button

Thanks!